# Using Stanford NLP to extract the purpose of a sentence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am looking into the various NLP libraries (specifically those which offer a command line for easy integration into my app).

I am curious - given a sentence such as *"I had to go to the store before 4:15 last Monday to get eggs, in order to complete baking my chocolate chip cookies"*

Is it possible to extract just the **purpose** behind the statement?

What I am hoping for:

*"Go to the store to get Eggs"*

I don't care about location, or time so much as I do the details I manually extracted.

Is this something NLP libraries can me me determine? If so, is a quick demo possible? So I can begin to wrap my head around this topic.

I am not interested in the follow up or reasoning, etc. Just the point of the statement.